# how to restore UBUNTU?

Tags: installation

I used to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP.  I have now deleted XP as I was not using it. But now the boot loader isn't working correctly.

How do I repair it?

Comment: I do not understand this sentence: "Ubuntu was my 1st priority XP was not operated". Also, please explain what exactly is not working with the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: He said that all he wanted to keep was Ubuntu and so he deleted Windows XP, and now he has to restore his grub2 bootloader (by doing what they say to do in this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) ).

Comment: If I have understood,and edited, the question correctly then this may be a duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/107450)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting off of a Live CD/USB drive and running boot-repair?  Boot-Repair fixes a lot of GRUB/boot issues, including my own.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create live Ubuntu USB with another computer.
2. Insert Live Ubuntu USB in the computer you need to repair boot loader.
3. Start the computer and keep pressing F2(or F12 or ESC depending on your computer bios) and enter into the bios set up.
4. Boot with USB and select Try Ubuntu.After Ubuntu booted with USB. In dash type terminal and enter.
5. In terminal enter the following command.
   sudo update-grub
6. Shut down your computer and remove USB flash drive. Start your computer again, Now you will get Ubuntu.